# Python - Nested groupby statements

Tags: python, sql, group-by, nested

Given a list_of_list from a SQL table, I'd like to analyze sets of adjacent rows dividing list_of_list for equal elements of column 2, then for equal element of column 1.
For example, given

```
list_of_list = [[1,1,3,2],
[1,3,3,2],
[1,3,6,2],
[1,3,6,2],
[1,5,5,2],
[1,3,5,2]]
```

I'd like to get to following output

```
[1,1,3,2]

[1,3,3,2]

[1,3,6,2]
[1,3,6,2]

[1,5,5,2]

[1,3,5,2]
```

What's wrong in the following code?

```
for key1, items1 in groupby(list_of_list, itemgetter(2)):
    for key2, items2 in groupby(items1, itemgetter(1)):
        for i in items2:
            print(i)
            print
```

it returns the following output

```
[1,1,3,2]

[1,3,3,2]

[1,3,6,2]

[1,3,6,2]

[1,5,5,2]

[1,3,5,2]
```

Comment: can you give us a sample `list_of_list` and expected output? Like `print(i)` and tell us what it's supposed to print.

Comment: ok, I added an example

Comment: Your code already does that though, after unindenting last print one level

Comment: I added also what my code returns

Comment: Yes, if you unindent the last print, your code will start printing expected output

Comment: Ah yes... I need to sleep maybe :) . Can I ask you something else here? How do you get the first element of items2?

Comment: I added an answer with the fixed syntax and an example of getting the first element from items2 without using index lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code works fine if you unindent the last `print` statement:

```
for key1, items1 in groupby(list_of_list, itemgetter(2)):
    for key2, items2 in groupby(items1, itemgetter(1)):
        for i in items2:
            print(i)
        print
```

To get the first element of `items2` you can use [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) like so:

```
first_of_items2 = next(items2, 'items2 was empty')
```

Comment: It looks like with "for key, items in groupby(list_of_list, itemgetter(2,1))" I obtain the same effect. Can you confirm that it's a fair way to use it?

Comment: Looks alright, you can check the docs if anything. I'll take a look too when I get home tonight. It seems as if it's grouping by one and then the other though, so it should be fine.

Comment: Just verified - it generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes, so all you need to do is use combined key - as long as your items are sorted by that key you're fine. For more info, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Good luck!